# GUN node added with SEA (gun.user()) not secure?

Tags: gun, gundb

After creation a new user, auth and adding some data. In second browser one can easily delete the data... What am I doing wrong?

First browser (Firefox private window):

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/gun.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/sea.js"></script>
    <script>
        localStorage.clear()
        var gun = Gun({ peers: ['http://localhost:8765/gun'] });
        var user = gun.user();
        user.create('u1','p1',()=>{
            user.auth('u1','p1', ()=>{
                user.set({some:'thing'}).on(() => {})
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second (Chrome incognito):

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/gun.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gun/sea.js"></script>
    <script>
        localStorage.clear()
        var gun = Gun({ peers: ['http://localhost:8765/gun'] });
        gun.on()
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Peer on port 8765 started with `http.js` from [examples](https://github.com/amark/gun/tree/master/examples).

After this in the second browser in the storage `localStorage.getItem('gun/')` I get nodes prefixed with `undefined` like: `undefined~@u1` and `undefinedSoulfofsomething` I also can delete content with `gun.get('Soulofsomething').put({some:null})`.
If this is normal behavior, how to protect data from attack? Only option is [bulletcatcher](https://github.com/zrrrzzt/bullet-catcher)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

> This should now be fixed in latest GUN `0.2020.421`!

@brezyl thank you for bringing up this issue, if you are seeing `undefined~@...` that definitely looks like a bug and that the data is not saving to where it should be saving (the protected user space).

I'll check into this urgently, I'll also send a notice out to the community if anybody is experiencing the same.

Until then, yes, **please use a different version of GUN & SEA**, or assume `undefined` is indication of erros/bugs going on resulting in security loss.

Updates:

@brezyl Update: So far I'm noticing that `.put(` seems to be OK, primitive value `.set(` seem OK, but `.set(object` NOT OK OR SAFE. Investigating further.

@brezyl update: I have found 2 ways to fix it, and will be doing both to add extra failsafes. Hopefully will be publishing ASAP (tests/review may take a while).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply!
I use gun 0.2020.401 as localhost peer.
I appreciate your work!

Comment: @brezyl Update: Security is important! Thank you for notifying me of this. So far I'm noticing that `.put(` seems to be OK, primitive value `.set(` seem OK, but `.set(object` NOT OK OR SAFE. Investigating further.

Comment: Update: I have found 2 ways to fix it, and will be doing both to add extra failsafes. Hopefully will be publishing ASAP (tests/review may take a while).

Comment: @brezyl fixed!!

Comment: Great! Thanks again!